# expressionengine 2.5.2 - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in

Tags: templates

I am new in expressionengine, and getting the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(680) : eval()'d code on line 153

Who know is this a security vulnerability ? Is there possible php code injection ?

Comment: It looks like an template parsing error and just that. Try to debug the template.

Comment: Have encountered similar, mine mostly due to bad if statement (s)